# Grails Async + Multi-Tenant Woes

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Using Grails 4.0.10 I have written most of a a discriminator-based multi-tenant app that works. The issue now is implementing a "janitor". It is a scheduled service that scans the database for documents past their deadline and assigns an "expired" state to them.

`Document` is a multi-tenant domain. The janitor is supposed to work across tenants.

The scheduled service spawns an async operation. Finding all candidate documents works as expected using `Tenants.withoutId`.

The problem comes when updating the database. Even though the logic is enclosed in `Tenants.withId` the operation ends with `TenantNotFoundException`. No tenant is found and the transaction is rolled back.

This happens when committing the transaction. Multiple `save()` operations and audit logging have completed without problem at that point.

To understand the source: The `Document` domain is associated with other domains: `Assignment` (plain), `AsmProgress` (multi-tenant), `DocAction` (multi-tenant). For a given document, all these belong to the same tenant. The `logRecordService` is an audit service.

Here is crucial source code.

```
  def forceExpireMultiple(InsUser actor, Map docActions) {
    if (log.debugEnabled) log.debug "FORCE_EXPIRE_MULTIPLE_S << ${actor}, ${docActions?.keySet()}"
    docActions.each {entry ->
      String caseId = entry.key
      DocAction docAction = entry.value
      // Each doc action is expired in its own transaction.
      DocAction.withTransaction {status ->
    if (log.traceEnabled) log.trace "forceExpireMultiple.ttag: ${docAction.ttag}"
    Tenants.withId(docAction.ttag) {
      docAction = get(docAction.id)
      doForceExpire(actor, caseId, docAction)
    }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Expire a single doc action with its assignments and document.
   */
  private doForceExpire(InsUser actor, String caseId, DocAction docAction) {
    if (log.debugEnabled) log.debug "DO_FORCE_EXPIRE_S << ${caseId}, ${docAction}"
    final String ttag = docAction.ttag

    // Terminate all assignments.
    docAction.assignments.each {assignment ->
      def progress = AsmProgress.of(assignment, ProgressType.EXPIRED)
      progress.ttag = ttag
      progress.save(failOnError: true)

      // The assignment is now done.
      assignment.stage = AsmState.FINISHED
      assignment.save(failOnError: true)
      logRecordService.logExpire(assignment, actor)
    }

    // Expire document.
    Document document = docAction.document
    document.expire()
    document.save(failOnError: true)
    logRecordService.logExpire(document, actor)

    // Expire the doc action itself.
    docAction.expire()
    docAction.save(failOnError: true)
    logRecordService.logExpire(docAction, actor)
  }
```

Here is some debug and stack trace output, edited for readability.

```
[pool-1-thread-1] se.insignia.web.DocActionService: FORCE_EXPIRE_MULTIPLE_S << [User global::policy], [FDH176]
[pool-1-thread-1] se.insignia.web.DocActionService: forceExpireMultiple.ttag: acme
[pool-1-thread-1] se.insignia.web.DocActionService: DO_FORCE_EXPIRE_S << FDH176, FDH176/acme(ACTIVE): ... (Acme Industries Ltd.)
[pool-1-thread-2] se.insignia.web.log.LogRecordService: Logging Assignment with tenantId [acme]
[pool-1-thread-3] se.insignia.web.log.LogRecordService: Logging Document with tenantId [acme]
[pool-1-thread-4] se.insignia.web.log.LogRecordService: Logging DocAction with tenantId [acme]
org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.exceptions.TenantNotFoundException: Tenant could not be resolved outside a web request
at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants.currentId(Tenants.groovy:73)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:100)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
at se.insignia.web.DocAction.withTransaction(DocAction.groovy)
at se.insignia.web.DocActionService$_forceExpireMultiple_closure6.doCall(DocActionService.groovy:262)
  [This is withTransaction in forceExpireMultiple]
at se.insignia.web.DocActionService.forceExpireMultiple(DocActionService.groovy:258)
```

From the debug output you can see that all of `doForceExpire` is executed, including audit logging, before the exception.

What's the root cause, and how can I find it out? Clearly some assumptions outside my own code are violated. What are they?

I have tried many variants of the code, including commenting out all audit logging.

Comment: Which tenant resolver are you using?  It looks like you are likely using one that requires an active request.

Comment: Right, a subdomain tenant resolver modeled on the one in the doco. Yes, its normal mode is to operate on a web request. But there also are supervising roles requiring access to other tenants. So far, "Tenants.withId" has done the job.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an answer and a theory for resolving the problem, I chose the solution [described in this post](https://dzone.com/articles/an-alternative-approach-to-threadlocal-using-sprin-1). The idea is to store the tenant id in thread local storage.

```
public class InsigniaExplicitTenantContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Serializable> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    public static void setTenantId(Serializable tenantId) {
      CONTEXT.set(tenantId);
    }

    public static Serializable getTenantId() {
      return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
      CONTEXT.remove();
    }
}
```

This means modifying the tenant resolver. Normally it deduces the tenant from the HTTP request. Now, if there is no web request, it checks thread local storage.

For convenience I also added a class emulating the `Tenants.withId` method:

```
class WithTenant {

  /**
   * Works as Tenants.withId but additionally stores the tenant id
   * in thread local storage.
   */
  static <T> T id(Serializable tenantId, Closure<T> callable) {
    Tenants.withId(tenantId) {
      InsigniaExplicitTenantContext.setTenantId(tenantId)
      callable.call()
    }
  }
}
```

The workaround is only needed in scheduled jobs where there obviously is no web request. So it's reasonably clean.

However, answers to the original question still are welcome. It's just that I couldn't wait any longer.